# How can I do a JOIN on nearby timestamps?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables containing measurements taken at different time intervals. The `left` table has less-frequent measurements and the `right` table has more-frequent measurements. I want to combine them so that the resulting table will contain every row in the `left` table, matched with whatever row in the `right` table has the closest time stamp.

So far, my lame solution takes advantage of the one-minute spacing of the rows in the `right` table. It is very slow and returns multiple rows for each row in `left` because there are multiple timestamp matches in the `right` table. How can I improve this?

```
SELECT `left`.*, `right`.*
FROM `left`
LEFT JOIN `right`
ON ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`left`.`timestamp`)/60) = ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`right`.`timestamp`)/60);
```

Comment: There aren't many ways to improve it because this is pretty much the right way to express your requirements in SQL.  If you were to store the `ROUND()`ed value in a column in both tables, then you could index  it which would speed up the join operation significantly.